# PIN number handling in j2me application

Tags: java-me

have to make a PIN protected j2me application, how can a default PIN number be applied to the application so that the user may have to change the PIN on the first run.

PS: PIN number is not the actual PIN number of the phone,it is application specific PIN

Answer (score 0):

Do you need for the default PIN to be different for different clients? If not, then have a default PIN and let the client know the PIN and provide an option to change the PIN after login.